# How to get the redirect url from Challenge()

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am using .net core web api and I need to get the redirect url like below and store it in variable.

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=1048870684189.....

Here's my code

```
            var properties = new AuthenticationProperties
            RedirectUri = "/api/user/ExternalLoginCallback"
            };

           return Challenge(properties, GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

Comment: Could you please tell me which application you have used? Asp.NET or asp.net core? Do you use some openidconnect owin middleware inside your application?